# How can I make a template tag inert in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, internet-explorer, html5-template

I have seen that there are polyfills to replicate the use of the html5 `<template>` element in internet explorer, but they all seem to be scripts that only end up hiding the template tag before activation. Unfortunately, this does not stop IE from rendering the content of the template. For example:

```js
var template = document.querySelector('#myTemplate');
var myNode = document.importNode(template.content, true);

//comment out the line below to de-activate the template.  
document.body.appendChild(myNode);
```

```html
<template id="myTemplate">
<h1>You should only see this when the template is activated</h1>
<script>alert('this alert should only be displayed when the template is activated.')</script>
</template>
```

In IE, the alert is displayed even when the template content is not being appended to document.body. I understand that the example code isn't exactly appropriate for IE because the template tag doesn't have a `content` property, but adding that property to the element doesn't stop the alert script from running.

Is there any way to make the contents of the template tag completely inert to IE or do I just have to wait until the template element is properly implemented for edge?

**Update(09/02/15):**

As minitech stated in the comments, it looks like there is no way to make the contents of a tag completely inert in ie. As an alternative, I am looking into suppressing any code that would be executed at the time of parsing by modifying the tag. It feels like an ugly hack, but it seems to work for now. I found the original polyfill here: http://jsfiddle.net/brianblakely/h3EmY/

markup:

```
<script>
    // Shim so we can style in IE6/7/8
    document.createElement('template');
</script>
<template id="example">
    <h1>This is template content.</h1>
    <p id="great">It's really great.</p>
    <script type="text/x-suppress">alert('hi')</script>
</template>
<div id="target">
    <p>This is regular old content.</p>
</div>
```

script:

```
/* POLYFILL */
(function templatePolyfill(d) {
    if('content' in d.createElement('template')) {
        return false;
    }
    var qPlates = d.getElementsByTagName('template'),
        plateLen = qPlates.length, elPlate, qContent, contentLen, docContent;
    for(var x=0; x<plateLen; ++x) {
        elPlate = qPlates[x];
        qContent = elPlate.childNodes;
        contentLen = qContent.length;
        docContent = d.createDocumentFragment();
        while(qContent[0]) {
            docContent.appendChild(qContent[0]);
        }
        elPlate.content = docContent;
    }
})(document);

/* EXAMPLE */
var elTemplate = document.getElementById('example').content.cloneNode(true),
    elTarget = document.getElementById('target');

//Comment out the line below to test if the script will run before template activation.
activateTemplate(elTarget, elTemplate);

/* Template Activation */
function activateTemplate(targetNode, sourceNode){
    var findScripts = sourceNode.querySelectorAll('script');

    for (var i = 0; i < findScripts.length; i++) {
        var testScript = findScripts[i];
        testScript.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    }
    targetNode.appendChild(sourceNode);
}
```

css:

```
template {
    display: none !important;
}
```

So can someone tell me why I would be stupid to use this method to suppress scripts being loaded within a template tag in ie? Can anybody tell me a better way of doing this?

Here is my jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/rqqvvaft/4/

Comment: No, there is no way to do that.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Would you be able to tell me if my update is not a viable solution?